# Oracle error on linux server when sending emails using sendmail

Tags: linux, oracle, sendmail, redhat

The ORACLE application is trying to send email using send mail running on a REDHAT LINUX server and the following error comes up, I don't have access to the code being a LINUX ADMIN and the application team sits on a remote location, just want to know what this error means exactly.

**> ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)**

When I check the mail Log files around the same time, I see the line below, kindly guide me through to solve this issue.

**sendmail[1812]: r6P80BgT001812: lost input channel from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] to Daemon0 after data**

Comment: Without seeing how the application is sending the mail - presumably via `utl_mail` or `utl_smtp` - and how/if it is specifying the recipients, and possibly how its mail functionality is being called, it's impossible to tell what's wrong. It isn't clear (to me) if the mail log error is related.

Comment: You may **temporarily* increase sendmail LogLevel to 15. It should give you transcript of incoming SMTP sessions in log files.